# モバイルアプリで「長押し」できることを表すデザイン

Tags: untagged

iOSやAndroidなどのモバイルアプリケーションのUIで、要素が長押し（ロングタップ）可能であることをユーザに伝えたい場合、それを伝えるよいデザインはありますでしょうか。

（例えばiOSのTableViewのCellでは、タップできる場合は右端に">"の印（Disclosure Indicator）を表示する、など）

Comment: アニメーションでマイクロインタラクションを与えるなどし、アイコン自体は指アイコンに時計アイコンを組み合わせることで押す時間を意識させるか、素直に文字を入れるかしてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: @Myaku おっしゃる通り説明文を入れるのが一番分かりやすいですね。「ユーザが長押しできることに気付かないかもしれない」と思った場合、そもそも長押しで画面を切り替えるというデザインを考え直した方がよいかもしれない、と質問後に気付きました。ただ、皆さんどうしているのかという素朴な疑問はあります。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Androidの場合はマテリアルデザインに例がありました。
長押し可のアイテム上で長押ししていると、円形の進捗が表示されるようにしているようです。

[Selection - Material Design](https://material.io/design/interaction/selection.html#item-selection)

また、実際のアプリでいくつか見てみると、長押ししているとその(リスト)項目が徐々にアニメーションでハイライトされていくものがありました。
他の一般的なアプリの場合には、指定時間長押しすると一瞬で選択(ハイライト)状態に切り替わるものが多い気がするので、それに比べれば多少分かりやすいのかなと思いました。
(ほんとに長押しを意識したデザインなのかは分かりませんが)

Comment: 頂いたリンク先の例で、ユーザが長押し操作を試すきっかけとしては「複数項目を選択したいけどそのコマンドが無い、あ、長押しするのか？」という感じですね。モバイルで複数選択する時には自然な操作ですので、このようなケースなら説明文なしでよいでしょうし、長押しの導入は自然に連想できる場合に限ったほうがよいと気付きました。ありがとうございます。